# Escaping comma in a Javascript object key

Tags: javascript, object, escaping

How can I access a JavaScript object key like "loc0,place" directly?

```
var resp = {"loc0,place":"50.9014731,6.9669255"}
```

It is inside a Apache Solr json response (pivot facet). The key can be renamed by choosing other fields, but the comma sign remains. I tried already some different notations, but without success:

```
console.log(resp.loc0,place);
console.log(resp."loc0,place");
console.log(resp.loc0\,place);
console.log(resp.loc0,,place);
```

Any idea?

Comment: With square brackets: `resp['loc0,place']`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/227299